# Removing duplicates from tuples within a list

Tags: python, list, duplicates, tuples

I have a list of tuples:

```
lst = [('a','b'), ('c', 'b'), ('a', 'd'), ('e','f'), ('a', 'b')]
```

I want the following output list:

```
output = [('a','b'), ('e','f')]
```

i.e I want to compare the elements of first tuple with remaining tuples and remove the tuple which contains either one or more duplicate elements.

My attempt:

I was thinking of using for loops, but that wont be feasible once i have very large list. I browsed through following posts but could not get the right solution:

[Removing duplicates members from a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009304/removing-duplicates-members-from-a-list-of-tuples)
[How do you remove duplicates from a list in whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

If somebody could guide me the right direction, it will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand the rule based on which you select the output.

Comment: All you need to do is implement the same idea as you would do for a list of integers, but just change the comparison function. So you would say `('a','b')` and `('a','d')` are equivalent and therefore drop the second one.

Comment: @millimoose If element `a` or element `b` match an earlier element then remove it, so `('c', 'b')` is a duplicate of `('a', 'b')`, and `('a', 'd')` is a duplicate of `('a', 'b')`.

Comment: I think a for loop over the elements is really your only option unless you have more information about the lists elements.

Comment: @GordonFreeman So they're less tuples, and more sets of characters then? (A tuple is usually considered a single value, not a collection.)

Comment: @Ben List comprehension would be faster.

Comment: you have to use some type of loops. if you need better performance you need to start with a better datastructure

Comment: Also, if the first element of the list is "special", it's a little confusing to have it be part of the list. Would be clearer if it was a separate variable.

Comment: Is the position of the 'a' or 'b' important? eg to you remove tuples with the fist item being 'b'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you want "duplicates" of all elements to be suppressed, and not just the first one, you could use:

```
lst = [('a','b'), ('c', 'b'), ('a', 'd'), ('e','f'), ('a', 'b')]

def merge(x):
    s = set()
    for i in x:
        if not s.intersection(i):
            yield i
            s.update(i)
```

gives

```
>>> list(merge(lst))
[('a', 'b'), ('e', 'f')]
>>> list(merge([('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'e')]))
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> list(merge([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('c', 'd')]))
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Sets should help:

```
>>> s = map(set, lst)
>>> first = s[0]
>>> [first] + [i for i in s if not i & first]
[set(['a', 'b']), set(['e', 'f'])]
```

Or with `ifilterfalse`:

```
>>> from itertools import ifilterfalse
>>> s = map(set, lst)
>>> [first] + list(ifilterfalse(first.intersection, s))
[set(['a', 'b']), set(['e', 'f'])]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. It works. Just a quick question: Do you see any performance issue (for eg: speed) if i were to use your first method i.e. [i for i in s if not i & first] instead of ifilerfalse? My list is big. Thanks!